# Not sure how to make a property on an object using Fluent NHibernate from custom query

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I am trying to map the following structure:

```
public class Tag {
   public Guid Id {get;set;}
   public DateTime ActivatedDate {get;set;}
}

public class History {
   public Guid Id {get;set;}
   public TypeEnum Type {get;set;}
   public Guid ContentID {get;set;}
   public DateTime HistoryDate {get;set;}
}
```

Tag.ActivatedDate is actually populated by `(select top 1 HistoryDate from History where ContentID = {tagid} && Type = 'Activated' order by HistoryDate desc`

I'm really not sure how to Map this with Fluent NHibernate.

My mappings are:

```
public TagMapping() {
   Table("Tags");
   Id(x => x.Id)     
}

public HistoryMapping() {
   Table("History");
   Id(x => x.Id);
   Map(x => x.Type).CustomeType<TypeEnum>();
   Map(x => x.ContentID);
   Map(x => x.HistoryDate);
}
```

I'm not sure how to map Tag.ActivatedTop

Basically looking for:

```
SELECT tag.Id,
       (select top 1 HistoryDate from History 
               where ContentID = tag.Id 
                AND Status = 'Activated' 
        order by HistoryDate desc) As ActivatedDate
FROM Tags tag
```

Comment: Did you mean ActivatedDate in "I'm not sure how to map Tag.ActivatedTop"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up doing:

```
  Map(x => x.ActivatedDate)
                .ReadOnly()
                .Formula(
                    string.Format(
                        "(select top 1 h.HistoryDate from History h where h.ContentID = Id AND h.Status = 'Activated' order by h.HistoryDate desc)"));
```

Comment: After doing this, I decided to do a bit of de-normalization and add the ActivatedDate column to my Tag Table.